# How to set download progress in a progress bar that is in a list view from thread?

Tags: android, multithreading, listview, progress-bar

I am using download manager for downloading a file.I want to show progress bar in the list view ,that showing download status.I am calculating the progress in a thread .When I try to set the progress from the thread it is not showing progress.What i should do in order to get the progress?
Here is my code

```
public Runnable updateprogress = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        try {
            Log.v("updateprogress in thread",""+killthread);

            if(killthread==false)
            {
                DownloadManager downloadmanager = (DownloadManager) context.getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);

                DownloadManager.Query q = new DownloadManager.Query();
                q.setFilterById(download_id);
                Cursor cursor = downloadmanager.query(q);
                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {

                    FileDownloading.setDownload_status(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS)));
                    long fileSize = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_TOTAL_SIZE_BYTES));
                    long bytesDL = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager
                            .COLUMN_BYTES_DOWNLOADED_SO_FAR));

                    int progress=(int) ((bytesDL * 100.0f) / fileSize);
                    FileDownloading.setDownload_progress((int) ((bytesDL * 100.0f) / fileSize));
                    if(fileSize!=-1){
                        PR_BAR.setIndeterminate(false);
                        FileDownloading.setDownload_progress(progress);
                        PR_BAR.setProgress((int) ((bytesDL * 100.0f) / fileSize));
                        if((int) ((bytesDL * 100.0f) / fileSize)==100){                             
                            killthread=true;
                            if(PR_BAR!=null)
                                PR_BAR.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            else
                                Log.e("progress bar","null");

                        }

                    }
                    else{
                        PR_BAR.setIndeterminate(true);
                    }

                } else {

                    FileDownloading.setDownload_progress(0);
                    FileDownloading.setDownload_status(-1);
                }
                cursor.close();
                mHandler.postDelayed(this, 5000);
            }
            else{
                updateprogress.wait();
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }


};
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be using [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) , implement onProgressUpdate()